# Android Studio - FindBugs excludeFilter file is working for IDEA plugin, but not for Gradle plugin

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, findbugs

I have the following exclude filter to ignore all R file classes:

**findbugs-exclude-filter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
    <Match>
        <Class name="~.*\.R\$.*"/>
    </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

When I use it for the FindBugs-IDEA plugin it works.

However, when I use it for the FindBugs Gradle plugin, in a task like so:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
task myFindBugsTask(type: FindBugs)  {

    .....

    excludeFilter = file("$project.rootDir/findbugs-exclude-filter.xml")

    .....
}
```

I get an error with the message: `Cannot read file specified for FindBugs 'excludeFilter' property:`. The report is still successfully generated, but the  filter didn't take.

I've tried EVERY solution I found on the interwebs (most of which are very outdated) and I get the same results.

So what gives? Is this a known bug? Am I the only one experiencing this?

Answer (score 2):

So I found a workaround if anyone is encountering the same issue. The concept is to submit a filtered file tree. My task now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
task myFindBugsTask(type: FindBugs)  {

    .....

    FileTree tree = fileTree("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes").exclude('**/*R$*.class')
    classes = tree

    .....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct filter:

```
 <Match>
     <Class name="~.*\.R(\$.*)?" />
 </Match>
```

This marches all `R` classes and inner classes.